# Why UIImage View showing wrong Size of Image

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator

I have image files of dimension 1900x1200. In my code I try to load it as

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

When I try to run this code in iPhone Simulator (Retina Display) my images look out of proportion. I tried to print

image.size.width and image.size.height

and the value I get is 950x600.

What I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is actually simple: the UIImageView (and the underlying UIImage) are using scale factor 2.0. That is your 1900x1200 *pixels* image correspond to 950x600 *points* image with scale factor 2 on retina display. You can double check the UIImage's scale property.

Comment: How to download an image with exact scale size with SDWebImage?