# AFNetworking setImageWithURL on UITableViewCell wrong size on Retina

Tags: uitableview, afnetworking

Using the simplest example of loading an image using the setImageWithURL with a 20x20px image ends up making the default cell's image view 10x10px instead.

If I load the image without AFNetworking's category method using the following code the image is set to 20x20 as expected:

Any clue as to why this is? 
(I fixed the previous code).

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Whatever"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Whatever"];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://acidblue.com/images/Gender_Male.png"]];
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://acidblue.com/images/Gender_Male.png"]]];
    }
```

Example Code can be found at: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ha9lw7suenolzb2/AFNetworkingCellExample.zip

There's also strange behavior as the icon from the AFNetworking call doesn't display immediately every time. I thought it was a thread issue, but I have checked and the icon is being set on the main thread. For now, if the icon doesn't show up, pull the table down and it will redraw. This is another issue I am having that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: just wanted to mention that I fixed the code so that it actually compiled but now I am not getting the behavior from a remote site. But I did just change AFNetworking's caching mechanism because I also kept getting nil images.

Comment: Hah, it is happening (I forgot to change the device to a Retina, funny!).

Answer (score 0):

set your imageview frame to 20x20

could you also provide the url of that image?

Comment: I had originally tried to set the value but it didn't change. Again, just odd behavior. I'm putting together a demo to see if I can get it to behave improperly again. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the inner workings of AFNetworking but it may be the same reason why, if you expect UIImage `size` to return pixels, you get "unexpected" values when querying on a Retina display. The reason is the conversion of pixels to points on the Retina display

from the Apple Reference

> @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGSize size
>
> In iOS 4.0 and later, this value reflects the logical size of the image and is measured in points. In iOS 3.x and earlier, this value always reflects the dimensions of the image measured in pixels.

See the following question and answer: (not specific to AFNetworking)

[Why UIImage View showing wrong Size of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084130/why-uiimage-view-showing-wrong-size-of-image)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's just odd that it works by loading from a synchronous network call to the URL but not from the async call. That's what has really confused me. I'll play more.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `contentMode` of `UIImageView` to "`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`".

```
self.avatarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,kAvatarDimension,kAvatarDimension)];
[self.avatarImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.avatarImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.avatarImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.comsomeimage.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar_default_black"]];
```